# Как выполнить AJAX в init.php битрикс24?

Tags: битрикс24

По определенному событию нужно выполнить AJAX-запрос из файла init.php.
Как это сделать?

Comment: AJAX-запрос не может быть выполнен из php файла, так как php файлы находятся и выполняется на сервере, а AJAX-запросы отсылаются из браузера javascript кодом.

Comment: т.е., через редирект только получается? По событию перебрасываем пользователя на страницу с формой, где и выполняем $('form').submit()? Другого варианта нет? Не хотелось бы пользователю показывать промежуточную страницу.